# Combining two queries from the same table using left join and group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Let's say I have the following table:

```
brand   | model   | country  | sales | year   | month
--------|---------|----------|-------|--------|-------
brand1  | model1  | US       | 10    | 2017   | 5
brand1  | model2  | US       | 11    | 2017   | 5
brand2  | model1  | US       | 5     | 2017   | 5
brand2  | model2  | US       | 18    | 2017   | 5
brand3  | model1  | US       | 8     | 2017   | 5
brand3  | model2  | US       | 12    | 2017   | 5 
brand1  | model1  | US       | 80    | 2016   | 5
brand1  | model2  | US       | 21    | 2016   | 5
brand2  | model1  | US       | 35    | 2016   | 5
brand2  | model2  | US       | 25    | 2016   | 5
brand3  | model1  | US       | 5     | 2016   | 5
brand3  | model2  | US       | 2     | 2016   | 5
brand1  | model1  | DE       | 5     | 2017   | 5
brand1  | model1  | DE       | 5     | 2017   | 4
brand3  | model2  | P        | 2     | 2016   | 5
```

I wanted to display the total sales for each brand in a specific country (US) in descending order for a specific month (5) of a specific year (2017). This is the query I wrote:

```
$country = str_replace ('-', '[- ]', $_GET['country']);
$year = $_GET['year'];
$month = $_GET['month'];
$previousyear = $year - 1;

$sql = "SELECT brand, SUM(sales) as sumsales
FROM `exampletable`
WHERE country REGEXP :country AND year = :year AND month = :month
GROUP BY brand ORDER BY sumsales DESC";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":country", $country);
$stmt->bindParam(":year", $year);
$stmt->bindParam(":month", $month);
$stmt->execute();
...
```

Then I thought it would be nice to add another column to the results displaying the sales figures for each brand in the same country for the same month (5) last year (2016). I tried to do this using `left join` but as you will notice my knowledge to develop these type of queries just isn't good enough...:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.brand, SUM(a.sales) as asumsales, SUM(b.sales) as bsumsales FROM exampletable a
LEFT JOIN exampletable b on a.brand = b.brand
WHERE a.country REGEXP :country AND b.country REGEXP :country AND a.year = :year AND b.year = :previousyear AND a.month = :month AND b.month = :month
GROUP BY brand ORDER BY asumsales DESC";
```

The expected result:

```
brand   | sales US, 2017, 5 | sales US, 2016, 5
--------|-------------------|-------------------
brand2  | 23                | 60
brand1  | 22                | 101
brand3  | 20                | 7
```

How can I get this result? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use conditional aggregation then you can do this in a single query:

```
SELECT
    brand,
    SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2017 AND month 5 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS sumsales1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2016 AND month 5 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS sumsales2
FROM exampletable
WHERE country = 'US'
GROUP BY brand
```

Note that you *could* join together two subqueries for each of the two sums you want, but that would be the harder way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation.  In your case, this would look like:

```
SELECT brand,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year = :year THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as sales_curr,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year = :year - 1 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as sales_prev
FROM exampletable
WHERE country REGEXP :country AND
      year IN (:year, :year - 1) AND
      month = :month
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY sales_curr DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is indeed the answer I was looking for but as Tim was the first to come up with this solution I accepted his answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Stan . . . I have great respect for Tim, but I answered because his answer doesn't use parameters.